# How to :bufdo only on modifiable buffers in vim?

Tags: vim

Sometimes I need to substitute across multiple buffers. For the purpose I use `:bufdo %s/old/new/gec`. Recently I noticed that the command fails when there is non-modifiable buffer in the buffer list (in my case it's opened file explorer/netrw). After running the command vim leaves me with `E21: Cannot make changes, 'modifiable' is off` and opened Netrw window.

Are the ways to `:bufdo` only on modifiable buffers? I've already tried `:bufdo!`, but the behaviour was the same (just without showing the error).

**UPDATE**

I find the line of `.vimrc` that poses this problematic behaviour:

```
let g:netrw_liststyle=3
```

I don't know what the magic here, but when I set this option neither of the suggested solutions/commands work for me. Now, the question is how to keep this line and make the `:bufdo` behaviour skip the buffer created by Netrw.

Comment: Have you tried to use bang? `:bufdo! %s/old/new/gec` I am not having Vim on me, so I can't try it:-)

Comment: Unfortunately, but it still leave me at the netrw tree. However, now it doesn't show any errors.

Comment: And does it substitute everything (what it can)? Or the command fails in other buffers?

Comment: Also you can consider `:argdo`. http://vimcasts.org/episodes/using-argdo-to-change-multiple-files/

Comment: The command fails in other buffers. Yeap, I use `:argdo/arga/args/argd` as the temporary solution, but I fed up of it) It much easier to do the same just with buffers.

Comment: `:bufdo` correctly avoids netrw buffers, here, even with my most minimal `vimrc`. Could you try without your `vimrc` (or with [my minimal `vimrc`](https://github.com/romainl/nanovimrc/blob/master/vimrc))?

Comment: It's strange, but without `vimrc` or with your minimal one the netrw can't be opened.. When I try to `:e.` vim just open new empty buffer and says `. is a folder`; typing `:E` throws `Not an editor command: E`. Wtf?)

Comment: @TimurFayzrakhmanov you need :set nocompatible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if `:bufdo sil! :%s/old/new/gec` does not work for you (this silently ignores errors). you need to wrap the command into an `if` statement. Something like this:

```
:bufdo if &ma | :%s/old/new/gec | endif
```

which checks for each buffer, if it is modifiable and only then attempts to replace old by new.

Note: You might also want to check for the `'readonly'` option in addition to the `'modifiable'` setting.

Comment: Unfortunately, but it doesn't work too. I found the line which makes me problem: `let g:netrw_liststyle=3` (makes default view as tree style listing). When I set this option neither of the suggested commands work.. So I what can I do with it? I like the tree view..

Comment: @TimurFayzrakhmanov but this works. Perhaps the if condition is not correct perhaps the netrw buffer is in fact modifiable. But then you need to find another condition? Perhaps the buffername?

Comment: I didn't understand your questions. What you're implying? What I want is just substitute among the buffers excluding non-modifiable ones and do it by the easiest way, like `bufdo  %s/old/new/gec`. I don't think the solution with if/endif is applicable, because I'm not going to type too long command - it's annoying..

Comment: @TimurFayzrakhmanov the `if..end` is the way to go. You asked for only doing this for modifiable buffers and that is how to do it. If you want it shorter, you can make a command for that or even map it. If you don't want the netrw window to be affected, you need to specify what option to check for. (perhaps the buffername of the `buftype` option

Comment: Anyway I was going to accept your answer) but you solution really doesn't work, but it does when I get rid of this option..so I think I need to create another question